# Using images from different Landsat missions and Sentinel-2 for machine learning

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, sentinel-2, random-forest, machine-learning

I am doing some image segmentation using random forests on satellite imagery. The events I am trying to detect are somewhat rare so my training sets are very limited if I want to use Sentinel-2 imagery since the earliest acquisition date is 2017.

Is it possible to train a machine learning model using images from different Landsat missions (and from Sentinel-2)? I am aware that the order of the bands differs from mission to mission, and the wavelength ranges differ (for example the green band of Landsat 7: B2 (0.52–0.60), However, the green band of Landsat 8: B3 (0.53–0.59))

If it is possible, what preprocessing steps should I make to homogenize the dataset for machine learning.

Comment: Perhaps consider something along the lines of what has been done here: https://hls.gsfc.nasa.gov/ or just using the data provided there.